# HashMap is not a valid property in JAXB class

Tags: java, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "InitiatePhoneCall", namespace = "namespace")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InitiatePhoneCall",
        namespace = "namespace",
        propOrder = {"messageParams"})

public class InitiatePhoneCall implements IRequest {

   // variables

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageParams", namespace = "namespace")
    private HashMap<String, Object> messageParams;

    public HashMap<String, Object> getMessageParams() {
        return messageParams;
    }

    public void setMessageParams(HashMap<String, Object> messageParams) {
        this.messageParams = messageParams;
    }

    //getter setters

}
```

I am having above code block in my application. I am using Weblogic 12c server with JDK 1.7. I am getting this in web service deployment:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class package.InitiatePhoneCall do not have a property of the name {namespace}MessageParams at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointArgumen‌​tsBuilder.java:610) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createArgumentsBuilder(TieHandler.java:143) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.(TieHandler.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.(DatabindingImpl.java:116)

Comment: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class package.InitiatePhoneCall do not have a property of the name {namespace}MessageParams
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:610)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createArgumentsBuilder(TieHandler.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.<init>(TieHandler.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:116)

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5331471/1346996) answer.

Comment: @XmlAnyAttribute is not working. I am getting same exception in webservice deployment.

Answer (score 0):

**1# Solution**

Use this `InitiatePhoneCall` class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "InitiatePhoneCall", namespace = "namespace")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InitiatePhoneCall",
        namespace = "namespace",
        propOrder = {"messageParams"})
public class InitiatePhoneCall implements IRequest {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="MessageParams",namespace="namespace")
    private HashMap<String, Object> messageParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public HashMap<String, Object> getMessageParams() {
        return messageParams;
    }

    public void setMessageParams(HashMap<String, Object> messageParams) {
        this.messageParams = messageParams;
    }
}
```

**2# Solution**

You can also use an `@XmlAdapter`

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, Object>> {

    public static class AdaptedMap {
        public List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    }

    public static class Entry {
        public String key;
        public Object value;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for(Entry entry : adaptedMap.entry) {
            map.put(entry.key, entry.value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            Entry entry = new Entry();
            entry.key = mapEntry.getKey();
            entry.value = mapEntry.getValue();
            adaptedMap.entry.add(entry);
        }
        return adaptedMap;
    }
}
```

`InitiatePhoneCall` class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "InitiatePhoneCall", namespace = "namespace")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InitiatePhoneCall",
        namespace = "namespace",
        propOrder = {"messageParams"})
public class InitiatePhoneCall implements IRequest {

    @XmlElement(name="MessageParams",namespace="namespace")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    private HashMap<String, Object> messageParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public HashMap<String, Object> getMessageParams() {
        return messageParams;
    }

    public void setMessageParams(HashMap<String, Object> messageParams) {
        this.messageParams = messageParams;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Xstian Thanks for the reply. the solution you gave resolved my issue. But my XSD is changed. As per my requirement the XSD file should not be changed

Comment: @ShankarVignesh you are right but your question you didn't talk about XSD. Anyway, provide us you complex types.

Comment: Existing XSD
<xs:element name="MessageParams" type="tns:hashMap" form="qualified" minOccurs="0"/>

New XSD
<xs:element form="qualified" name="MessageParams">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

Comment: But if you have already an XSD you could try to generate JAXB classes using `<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>` in order to mantain that definitions.

Comment: We are not using maven in our project. We are using Ant 1.7.1

Comment: No problems :) .. you could use XJC by command line, also with Ant [See Here](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html)

Comment: I have used XJC with ant to generate JAXB classes. Again i got same error. The JAXB class was similar to the original class which caused the issue.

Comment: @ShankarVignesh i added another solution, let me know.

Comment: I have already tried the solution. This solution also results in XSD change.

Comment: @ShankarVignesh if i had known your constraint about the XSD i avoided the answer. Anyway, for me and for the question explained above, it has been solved. Feel free to up vote.

Comment: Any other answers for this question without changing XSD??